# how to use string as reference in java?

Tags: java, android, string, reference, android-edittext

i have EditText reference set as "dimrix_1" .
i have string that has value as "dimrix_1" .

how can i use the string as the reference in case i dont know the value of the string so if it will be "dimrix_2" i would like to refer to "dimrix_2" EditText and so on ...

```
dimrix_1 = (EditText) mRoot
        .findViewById(R.id.dimrix_et);
dimrix_2 = (EditText) mRoot
        .findViewById(R.id.dimrix2_et);
dimrix_3 = (EditText) mRoot
        .findViewById(R.id.dimrix3_et);


String ManNotNeeded = "dimrix_" + totalNumbers;
```

now i want go make the editText that match "ManNotNeeded" value to setVisibility(View.GONE)

hope i was clear on the explanation ...

update :

```
            int r = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    "edit_text_id", "id",
                    getActivity().getPackageName());
dimrix_1 = (EditText) mRoot
        .findViewById(r);
```

this suggest here but i don't want to use the original xml id . i want to use the reference if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The method `android.content.res.Resources.getIdentifier()` does what you want. For the details have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: i"m trying to use the reference i created before instead of original xml id . look at my edit .  thanks !

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Why not using `getResources().getIdentifier(
                    ManNotNeeded, "id",
                    getActivity().getPackageName());

Comment: it wont work , instead of ManNotNeeded you will need to write the view id inside the xml . otherwise r = 0 .

Comment: Sure, in the xml layout you need to specify static ids. Maybe rephrase your question to make clear what you need.